# Title and bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, titles

I have found a code that change the title presentation for each chapters of my document. However, this change the title placement of the bibliography. Is there a method to raise the title of the bibliography? See figures for the program.

Any help will be highly appreciated :)

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside,10pt,oldfontcommands]{memoir}   %oldfontcommands \sc memoir
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{standalone}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\newcommand{\chaptercolor}{black}

%\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}  %Control the caption size e.g.
\makeatletter
\newcommand\HUGEr{\@setfontsize\Huge{50}{60}} %used to set the number in chapter section
\makeatother    

\usepackage[detect-all]{siunitx} %detect-all for making italic in caption
\usepackage{tikz}

\bibliographystyle{unsrt} %make the citation appear in right sequnce 1 2 3 4


\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\filcenter}
{\tikz[remember picture,overlay]
    {\node[fill=\chaptercolor,%<--- Not hardcoded color
        font=\sffamily\fontsize{50}{40}\bf\selectfont\color{white},anchor=north east, 
        minimum width=3cm, 
        minimum height=3cm] 
        at (7,0) 
        (numb) {\thechapter};
        \node[rotate=90,
        anchor=south,
        inner sep=0pt,
        font=\Huge\sffamily]
        at (numb.west) {\SPREAD\chaptertitlename};%<-- Not hardcoded "CHAPTER"
}}
{3.5cm}
{\Huge\bfseries\color{\chaptercolor}#1\vspace*{-3cm}}%< Not hardcoded color


%Spread the word out in chapter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\SPREAD}{m}
{% full expand the argument
    \vincent_spread:f { #1 }
}
\cs_new_protected:Npn \vincent_spread:n #1
{% with \tl_map_inline:nn we insert \hfil between letters; a final \unskip kills the last \hfil
    \makebox[3cm][s]{\tl_map_inline:nn { #1 } { ##1 \hfil } \unskip}
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \vincent_spread:n { f }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Comment: I suggest you use another format for unnumbered chapters, like this: `\titleformat{\name=chapter, numberless}[block]{ ... }`.

Comment: Can you give me better description on how to do that? I am unfortunately not a master of Latex :(

Comment: I've posted a complete code. If it results in something not like you want, please let me know.

Comment: You really should not be using titlesec with memoir

Comment: Daleif - I know that you are a very busy man, but can you find the time to correct it, so I learn the proper way of doing it?

Comment: On vacation, so haven't got any running pcs. Plus it is not at all clear what it is you're trying to do, especially your mwe is not compilable. If you want to do stuff with titlesec and aren't relying on memoir features (yet), switch to book, it is compatible with titlesec, memoir is not.

Comment: BTW I recognised the style, see https://ctan.org/tex-archive/info/MemoirChapStyles?lang=en for a non-tikz based version of it for memoir. The daleif1, I made it for my book at one time, then latex moved on.

Comment: Also remember @name when you reply, then we gat a ping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use  something like this in your preamble:

```
\titleformat{name=\chapter, numberless}[block]{\normalfont\filcenter\Huge\bfseries}{}{0pt}{#1}
```

All unnumbered chapters will be formatted with this code.

When I use this code in my preamble is gives me the following error message:

[image]

Comment: Too many }'s. ...block]\normalfont\filcenter\Hude\bfseries}
Missing \begin{document}. ...k]\normalfont\filcenter\Hude\bfseries}{}{0
You can't use `macro parameter character #' in horizontal mode. ...rmalfont\filcenter\Hude\bfseries}{}{0pt}{#
Undefined control sequence. \begin{thebibliography}{1}
Missing number, treated as zero. \begin{thebibliography}{1}
Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). \begin{thebibliography}{1}
The \bf font command is deprecated. (memoir) Use \textbf{...} or {\bfseries... } instead

Comment: You can insert screenshots  via the icon looking like a mountain in the toolbar of the edit window.

Comment: What I posted misses an opening brace just after `[block]` – and there's a typo: you wrote `\Hude` in the place of `\Huge`. Sorry for that. Please try with  the modified code.

Comment: Thank you very much for explanation and your patience. Your post has gotten the acceptence.

Comment: Thank you! Feel free to ask if you have any difficulties to adjust the code to your exact needs.